# android Interstitial ads & banner ads

Tags: java, android, google-apps

I want to use google ads for my project .
I can show banner and Interstitial ads base on document exist in developers google. 
in this document use different id for testing banner and Interstitial ads.
I want to know , is it possible to get just one id for both banner & Interstitial ads?
are they same? or they are completely different .

Answer (score 0):

Both are different ads and you can't use the same ID for both types of ads, For more details see this [link](https://onlinesales.ai/blog/app-installs-interstitial-ads-banner-ads/)